# why does order matters?

Tags: c++

why is it that when i put `cin.clear()` then `cin.ignore()` the program works flawlessly, ex: i put in `chars` and the program doesn't bug.

but when i put `cin.ignore()` first then `cin.clear()`, the program doesn't stop sending error signals.

how does this work?

shouldn't the input be erased and the `fail flag` unset?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class time
{
private:
int hours;


public:
void getime()
{
do
   {
   cout << "Enter hours: ";
   cin >> hours;
   if ( hours < 0 || hours > 23 || cin.fail()  )
   {
       cin.clear();
       cin.ignore(10,'\n');
       cerr << "invalid time, minutes must be between 0 and 59 " << endl;


   }
   }while(hours<0 || hours>23);
}
   };

int main()
{
    time asd;
    asd.getime();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider rephrasing the question to "why `cout << "hello world"; return;` works and why `return; cout << "hello world";` does not?"

Comment: ouch, im noob, please be gentle hahah.

Comment: @korek cin.clear() does not do anything to the buffer. It simply resets the flags. As such, it probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: that is what it makes me wonder, since cin.clear only affects one byte, that has nothing to do with the buffer, why does the order matters?

Comment: well think about it, if you have a failed status bit, why would you try to do anything with the stream? even an `ignore()`?

Answer (score 6):

`cin.clear(); cin.ignore(10,'\n');` clears the stream's error flags to make it readable again, and then tries to skip up to 10 characters to the end of a line.

`cin.ignore(10,'\n'); cin.clear();` first tries to skip up to 10 characters to the end of a line (which will fail and do nothing if the stream is in an error state), and then it clears the stream's error flags to make it readable again. Then you go around the loop and attempt again to read the ill-formatted data that caused it to fail last time.

If the question is, "why can't I use `ignore` to discard data from a stream that's in an error state" then, erm, you just can't. The way streams are designed to be used is that they go into an error state and sit there doing nothing until you either know how to fix it (and `clear()` them to say you're ignoring the error) or else give up and quit.